# How do you hide the "Features" pane in TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'm running TFS 2015 on-prem. How do you hide the "Features" pane in the backlog view?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click "Mapping". In the screenshot you provided, it's set to "On". Turning it off will hide the Features pane.